# How to resolve the couldn't find a device to launch issue, while launching the appium for ios?

Tags: ios, appium, inspector

1. I am using 1.3.6 appium version. When I click the launch button I am getting the below issue .

info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1

info: [debug] Checking whether instruments supports our device string

info: [debug] Getting list of devices instruments supports

info: [debug] Instruments is at: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments`

info: [debug] Getting device string from opts:

```
{"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 5s (E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B)","platformVersion":"7.1"}
```

info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 5s (E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B) (7.1 Simulator)'

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

```
error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPhone 5s (E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B) (7.1 Simulator)', but the available devices were: ["iPad 2 (8.1 Simulator) [3DD93343-67D4-4EAD-92AA-C005B7933E6D]","iPad Air (8.1 Simulator) [77400AA8-80E0-4ECB-ADCD-08DF3767B57E]","iPad Retina (8.1 Simulator) [A6C0CF5A-255B-4029-AE95-569DA7B29B90]","iPhone 4s (8.1 Simulator) [9CA88BC6-E3ED-44CA-89D8-05487C88A944]","iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator) [C68E6A43-DBE7-4D85-9CE5-BB87B9915BB0]","iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator) [E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B]","iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator) [4391D23F-BA21-4FB8-8887-0972D2911420]","iPhone 6 Plus (8.1 Simulator) [71B23D13-3F3F-4828-910A-2FAEEABD1C1A]"]
```

**error: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Could not find a device to launch.**

`You requested 'iPhone 5s (E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B) (7.1 Simulator)', but the available devices were: ["iPad 2 (8.1 Simulator) [3DD93343-67D4-4EAD-92AA-C005B7933E6D]","iPad Air (8.1 Simulator) [77400AA8-80E0-4ECB-ADCD-08DF3767B57E]","iPad Retina (8.1 Simulator) [A6C0CF5A-255B-4029-AE95-569DA7B29B90]","iPhone 4s (8.1 Simulator) [9CA88BC6-E3ED-44CA-89D8-05487C88A944]","iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator) [C68E6A43-DBE7-4D85-9CE5-BB87B9915BB0]","iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator) [E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B]","iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator) [4391D23F-BA21-4FB8-8887-0972D2911420]","iPhone 6 Plus (8.1 Simulator) [71B23D13-3F3F-4828-910A-2FAEEABD1C1A]"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the logs I imagine you are attempting to launch the app on a simulator. The reason your launch failed was because you requested a simulator with 7.1, since you don't seem to have these you will need to go into Xcode preferences->downloads and download the older iOS sims. Also as a tip, for simulators you do not need to add the UDID as part of the name. Try to only use the UDID for physical devices.

Comment: I am trying to connect using physical device. It doesn't recognize the physical device. It list the simulator alone.

Answer (score 1):

Try using either the device device description -

```
(iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator))
```

or the udid -

```
(E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B)
```

**NOT BOTH.**

Also, one more thing :
as per logs, its says that -

```
You requested 'iPhone 5s (E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B) (7.1 Simulator)'
```

but the available devices as per logs matching the device id :

```
[E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B]
```

is on v8.1 not v7.1 -

```
"iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator) [E5723F7E-05AC-4858-9C9F-495C1FA3A00B]"
```

so should crosscheck platformVersion carefully as well before running.

For reference - http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5758355129761792

Answer (score 0):

Try to disconnect and connect the device again. This happened to me a lot of times but works by just disconnecting and connecting it again.